# Jquery placement gives different results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue that's driving me bonkers. 
Im using a _Layout.cshtml file with Scripts rending on top.

from _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
<!-- CSS Start -->
        <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- CSS End -->
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<!-- Javascript Start -->
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/customJS.js"></script>
<!-- Javascript End -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
```

All scripts works like a charm, except one thing. I'm using a code in a webgrid that displays data on hover using popover()
from customJS.js

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Every thing work well, untill i use webgrid paging or sorting, then the code breaks an i need to reload the page to make it work. Now to the kicker, if i place all scripts on the bottom the popover works while paging and sorting but my jquery-ui dialogs breaks and won't display, plus i get jquery undefined errors.

I have spent some time now searching and trying different solutions with no correct result in sight. What am i doing wrong?

Here is the code for the popover call also

```
FileGrid.Column("Description", style: "width-20", format: @<button role="button" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="popover" title="File Information" data-content="@item.Description" data-trigger="focus"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> View file Description</button>),
```

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue with the jquery loading correctly by invoking
`$(document).ready`

Comment: Now i only need to fix the **'jQuery' is undefined** i get because i moved the Javascripts to the bottom of the _Layout.cshtml